# Is it possible in three js to outline the edges of shapes in three.js?

Tags: three.js

I have the following 3d scene generated, with square "timber". I would like to add outlines to the shapes, but not show the triangles that make up the rectangles. Is that possible? I am also addind side walls, made out of different planks, but the problem is it looks like 1 big rectangle, instead of multiple planks. That's why I would like to show the outline of the rectangle, but don't want to show the triangles. I would like to do cartoon like lines.

[image: Triangles]

Comment: Have a look at [`THREE.EdgesGeometry()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/geometries/EdgesGeometry).

Comment: Prisoner849: that's it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answer provided by Prisoner849. I can now build my model with clear lines.

[image]